# Swift: ползунок аудио трека подлагивает

Tags: ios, swift, slider

В моем приложении есть аудиоплеер. И ползунок для перемещения звуковой дорожки. Но, например, в моем приложении на экране блокировки ползунок не подлагивает, когда его скролишь влево вправо. И он не пытается проигрывать аудио в момент перемотки. Когда его зажимаешь он продолжает проигрывает аудио, а проигрывать новое время он начинает только после отпускания ползунка. Поесть он нормально работает как в Apple Music.

А внутри моего приложения тоже слайдер и он зависает, когда я его скроллю. И чем больше размер аудиофайла, тем сильнее зависает ползунок при прокрутке. То есть если я его из начала трека перемещаю в конец, то попутно он цепляет куски аудио трека и пытается проиграть их. А не плавно перемещается как на заблокированном экране. Как это исправить?

```
@IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
    musicOperation.cancelAllOperations()
    let operation = BlockOperation()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
    musicOperation.addOperation(operation)
}
```

**Update**

В `updateTime()` закомментировал `slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)` это помогло убрать подергивания и мигание. Но в `fastForward()` и `fastBackward()` при нажатии трек перематывался, но слайдер был на месте поэтому закомментировал в этих функциях вызов `//updateTime()` и добавил вместо `slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)`. Помогло.

Так же слайдер перестал запоминать свое местоположение при блокировке экрана, перемотке трека на заблокированном экране и следующем возвращении в приложение. Потому что как писал ранее убрал эту строку `slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)` в `updateTime()`. Поэтому решил добавить вызов `applicationWillEnterForeground`. Правильно ли я все сделал?

Осталась проблема 3. И еще два маленьких вопроса:

4. Я так понимаю что мне вообще не нужно использовать `musicOperation` верно?
5. После того как начал использовать `Touch Up Inside` появилось странное поведение. Например, если я передвигаю туда сюда ползунок в +- вертикальных рамках слайдера (то есть его размер 30 по стандарту, а палец я держу чуть выше или ниже) то все нормально. Но если я зажму слайдер а палец уведу на верх экрана iPhone или вниз, то я увижу как бы анимацию отжимания ползунка, но все равно смогу им управлять. И если я отожму палец и ползунок остановится, то он просто не выполнит свою функцию. Аудио не переключится на выбранное место. Раньше до использования `Touch Up Inside` делал тоже самое уводил палец вверх не отжимая слайдер при этом видел анимацию отжимания, но после отпускания пальца трек играл в месте остановки ползунка

   ```
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    let musicOperation = OperationQueue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)

    musicOperation.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1       
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "m4a")!

        do {

            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)

            setupMediaPlayerNotificationView(true)
            lockScreen()

        } catch {

        }

    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
            audioPlayer.play()
            slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
            restorePlayerCurrentTime()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func fastForward(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: TimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time += 15.0 // Go Forward by 15 Seconds
        if time > audioPlayer.duration {
            audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(audioPlayer, successfully: true)
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
            slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime) //updateTime()
        }
        self.lockScreen()
    }

    @IBAction func fastBackward(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: TimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time -= 15.0 // Go Back by 15 Seconds
        if time < 0 {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime) //updateTime()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
            slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime) //updateTime()
        }
        self.lockScreen()
    }

    private func restorePlayerCurrentTime() {
        let currentTimeFromUserDefaults : Double? = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)") as! Double?
        if let currentTimeFromUserDefaultsValue = currentTimeFromUserDefaults {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = currentTimeFromUserDefaultsValue
            slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes = currentTime/60
        let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

        let durationTime = Int(audioPlayer.duration) - Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes1 = durationTime/60
        let seconds1 = durationTime - minutes1 * 60

        timeElapsed.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
        timeDuration.text = NSString(format: "-%02d:%02d", minutes1,seconds1) as String

        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(durationTime, forKey: "durationTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")

        //slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        let currentTime = 0
        let durationTime = 0.1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(durationTime, forKey: "durationTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        timer?.invalidate()

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/\(masterIndex)/\(index+1).mp3"))

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){

            if endOfChapterSleepTimer == true {
                endOfChapterSleepTimer = false
            } else {
                index = index + 1
                viewDidLoad()
            }

        } else {

        }
    }

    @IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
        musicOperation.cancelAllOperations()
        let operation = BlockOperation()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
        self.lockScreen()
        musicOperation.addOperation(operation)
    }

    @objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification)  {
        slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Назначьте проигрывание после перемотки на событие `touchUpInside`, то есть на момент отпускания слайдера

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderTouchUpInside(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

```
@IBAction func sliderTouchUpInside(_ sender: UISlider) {
    musicOperation.cancelAllOperations()
    let operation = BlockOperation()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(time)
    musicOperation.addOperation(operation)
}
```

**Update**

Здесь пример работы с плеером на основе вашего кода, `BlockOperation` здесь не требуется, касательно события `Touch Up Inside` - как следует из названия, это события завершения касания *внутри* контрола, чтобы отработать завершение касания и за его пределами, я добавил обработку `Touch Up Outside`. Также я уменьшил частоту срабатывания таймера, 0.5 сек вполне достаточно, если вы выводите время с точностью до секунд.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var timeElapsed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var timeDuration: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var timer: Timer?
    var isRewindMode = false
    
    // MARK: --
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)),
            name:UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
            object: nil)
        
        slider.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(sliderTouchUp(_ :)),
            for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
        
        slider.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(sliderTouchDown(_ :)),
            for: .touchDown)
        
        slider.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_ :)),
            for: .valueChanged)
        
        setupTestPlayback()
    }
    
    // MARK: Playback
    
    private func setupTestPlayback() {
        do {
            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            
            let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                                    mode: .default,
                                    policy: .longFormAudio,
                                    options: [])
            try session.setActive(true, options: [])
            
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "0", withExtension: "mp3")!
            
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            
            if !audioPlayer.prepareToPlay() {
                print("failed to prepare playback")
                return
            }
            
            restorePlayerCurrentTime()
            play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    private func setPlayerCurrentTime(_ time: Float) {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(time)
    }
    
    private func togglePlayback() {
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            pause()
        } else {
            play()
        }
    }
    
    private func play() {
        audioPlayer.play()
        playButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 0.5, // no need to set too frequent period
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(updateTime),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }
    
    private func pause() {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        playButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
    
    @objc func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes = currentTime / 60
        let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
        
        let durationTime = Int(audioPlayer.duration) - Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes1 = durationTime / 60
        let seconds1 = durationTime - minutes1 * 60

        timeElapsed.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds) as String
        timeDuration.text = NSString(format: "-%02d:%02d", minutes1, seconds1) as String

        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "currentTime")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(durationTime, forKey: "durationTime")

        if !isRewindMode {
            slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        }
    }
    
    private func restorePlayerCurrentTime() {
        let currentTime = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "currentTime")
        setPlayerCurrentTime(currentTime)
        slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    }
    
    // MARK: UI Events
    
    @IBAction func playButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        togglePlayback()
    }
    
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        isRewindMode = true
        
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            // rewind time if playback is stopped
            setPlayerCurrentTime(sender.value)
            updateTime()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func sliderTouchUp(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(#function)
        setPlayerCurrentTime(sender.value)
        isRewindMode = false
    }
    
    @IBAction func sliderTouchDown(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(#function)
        isRewindMode = true
    }
    
    @objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification)  {
        restorePlayerCurrentTime()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController : AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    // TODO: implement
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно это сделать через код как Вы в ответе написали или через сториборд можно?

Comment: @user можно и через сториборд, там есть в списке  событий для слайдера при создании `IBAction` пункт `Touch Up Inside`

Comment: Так и сделал. Только есть несколько проблем. 1. у Вас в коде `audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(time)` я получаю ошибку `No exact matches in call to initializer` Поэтому я оставил как есть у себя. 2. Слайдер работает плавно но ползунок раздваивается и мигает посередине. 3. Это не совсем проблема, но на заблокированном экране слайдер работает плавно и при его перемотке время пройденное и оставшееся тоже меняются. В моем случае они не меняются в зависимости от передвижения ползунка

Comment: @user по 2 и 3 вопросу сложно дать конкретный ответ, пожалуйста дополните свой вопрос, постаравшись представить минимальный пример, чтобы я смог его воспроизвести и проверить - например у вас опущено объявление переменных `musicOperation` и `audioPlayer` и другая логика воспроизведения

Comment: Добавил новый код после заголовка **Update** и описание

Comment: @user ок я гляну

Comment: @user я обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает. Я принял ответ. Но не было времени прокомментировать. Есть вопросы. 1. когда трек играет и я начинаю скролить все работает плавно, но при этом время на таймерах не меняется при перемотке. Например, если я использую плеер на заблокированном экране, то в момент перемотки(палец не отпускаю с ползунка) я слышу как играет текущий трек, а на таймерах вижу как меняется время в зависимости от того куда я переместил ползунок. А когда отпускаю ползунок трек перематывается. Как это сделать? Потому что так пользовать видит на какой секунде ему нужно остановить палец.

Comment: 2. Если использую код из ответа, ставлю на паузу воспроизведение и начинаю перематывать слайдер тоже подлагивает. Потому что выполняется код после этой строчки `// rewind time if playback is stopped`